# Parsing output from SC command in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am struggling really hard with parsing the output of the SC.EXE command. I want to list all services (active or inactive) that have "text" in their name.

The following code is looking for eventlog:

```
FOR /F "usebackq" %%G IN (`"sc query state= all" ^| find "eventlog"`) DO echo [%%G]
```

It would all work if it was not for the `state= all` parameter that you need to pass to the SC command so that you will get even inactive services.

For some not so clear reason the values for parameters in the SC command need to be separated by space and that's causing a lot of confusion.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%s in ('sc query state^= all ^| findstr /i /B /R "SERVICE_NAME:.*event" ') do echo %%s
```

Use the colon as delimiter and filter the lines for the SERVICE_NAME text at start of line followed by any text that contains event, retrieving the second token (the name of service after colon ).

Answer (score 1):

```
FOR /F %%G IN ('sc query state^= all ^| find /i "eventlog"') DO echo [%%G]
```

would appear to find `eventlog`, echoing `[SERVICE_NAME:]

Answer (score 0):

To keep the second part and use colon space as the delims assuming there are no spaces in the SERVICE_NAME value.

```
sc query state= all | find "SERVICE_NAME" | find "SQL"

SERVICE_NAME: MSSQLFDLauncher
SERVICE_NAME: MSSQLSERVER
SERVICE_NAME: MSSQLServerOLAPService
SERVICE_NAME: SQLBrowser
SERVICE_NAME: SQLSERVERAGENT
SERVICE_NAME: SQLTELEMETRY
SERVICE_NAME: SQLWriter
```

Use the tokens 2 and this will take the second part of the above and DO and echo of that value. In dos file use %%A. But here the %A will be used. You can use a %B if you have more tokens 2,3. in the for body escape anything that would be interpreted by the initial entry of the dos.

```
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=: " %A IN ('sc query state^= all ^| find "SERVICE_NAME"') DO @echo [%A] | find "SQL"


[MSSQLFDLauncher]
[MSSQLSERVER]
[MSSQLServerOLAPService]
[SQLBrowser]
[SQLSERVERAGENT]
[SQLTELEMETRY]
[SQLWriter]
```